# What is the order of $\langle A,B\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I found out that

> $\langle A ,B \rangle:= \langle A \cup B \rangle$

Suppose that $ord(\langle A \rangle)=n<\infty$ and $ord(\langle B \rangle)=m<\infty$. What is the order of $\langle A ,B \rangle$?

Comment: You can only say that $|\langle A, B\rangle|$ is divisible by $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer vary by the choice of $A$ and $B$. For example consider $\mathcal{D_4}$ symmetry group of a square. Take $A=r $ rotation by $\pi/2 $ and $B=r^2$. Then $ \text{ord}\left(A\right)=4 $ and $ \text{ord}\left(B\right)=2 $, and $ \text{ord}\left\langle A,B\right\rangle =|\left\{ id,r,r^{2},r^{3}\right\} |=4 $.

Now take $B=s$ where $s $ is a reflection with respect to the real axis, then also $ \text{ord}\left(B\right)=2$, but now $ \left\langle A,B\right\rangle =\mathcal{D}_{4} $ so that $ \text{ord}\left\langle A,B\right\rangle =8 $

Comment: So there is no general rule I can follow, right? I can only check for every different element of $A$ and $B$

Comment: @GiorgosMitropoulos Yes. As you can see I found 2 different results for different $A,B$ with the same order.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: I am sorry for asking a low quality question, but I sincerly could not find a good dublicate. My college book doesn't even mention the notation $\langle A ,B \rangle$. I am sorry if I wasted your time.